# Betrayal at House on the Hill -- what counts as a turn for attacks?

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

For the monster turn -- if I have several zombies (as an example), can they each attack on the turn? So, I move one zombie and attack someone, and then I move another and attack someone else? Until I have moved and/or attacked with each zombie? Just want to make sure we are understanding the definition of "turn".

Answer (score 4):

The Traitor always gets to move and attack with each monster, separately, after they have finished their own turn (unless a Haunt-specific rule tells you otherwise, of course).

From the [second edition rulebook](http://media.wizards.com/2015/rules/betrayal_rules.pdf) (page 17, or page 12 if you are cross-referencing the first edition rulebook):

> After you finish your turn, you move and attack with all of the monsters, if any.

Answer (score 1):

After the Haunt there are three turn phases

## Player Turns

In this phase every player gets their turn

## Traitor Turn

In this phase the traitor gets a turn

## Monster Turns

In this phase if the traitor controls monsters that get to move such as minions or what ever they each get their turn here.